# node.js and mySQL issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am running a query which gives me confusing results. I have a node.js server which takes some user input from a form on the client side and uses socket.io to get the input on the server. here is the function which runs after receiving user input

```
databaseCheck(data);

function databaseCheck(userInput){

  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : '12.34.56.78',
   user     : 'user',
   password : 'password',
   database : 'db'
  });
 connection.connect();

 var query = connection.query('SELECT * from `table` WHERE `email` = userInput', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err) console.log(rows[0].username);   
  else console.log("connection failure");
 });

 connection.end();
}
```

So when ever I use this code, it keeps printing "connection failure" to the screen. It doesn't happen when I replace userInput with the "example@email.com" so I'm guessing there is some problem with using the variable userInput in the query. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you need to pass the `userInput` by appending it to the string, you need to escape it so that the query recognizes it as a string:

```
connection.connect();

var query = 'SELECT * from `table` WHERE `email` = ' + JSON.stringify(userInput);

console.log(query);

connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err) console.log(rows[0].username);   
  else console.log(err.name, err.message);
});

connection.end();
```

It also helps to make the error message more informative by displaying the actual error instead of a generic message.

<s>Lastly, put connection.end(); inside the callback.</s> According to what you said, it appears to work like you had it <s>but it's generally a bad idea to end a connection before an asynchronous process using the connection has called back.</s>

Ignore my last comment, it appears I was wrong in this particular case. According to [the repository documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction), it says:

> Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I also noticed it works when I use this: var query = 'SELECT * from `table` WHERE `email` = " ' + userInput + ' ";

Comment: @Jay that method only works if `userInput` does not contain `"` otherwise your SQL query would be vulnerable to code injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for testing and resolution. Printing to the log will let you see what you are putting in the query.

> var querystring = "SELECT * from `table` WHERE `email` LIKE " +
>   userInput;
>
> console.log(querystring);
>
> var query = connection.query(querystring, function(err, rows, fields) {...

Comment: I edited the question. It never prints the first user now, it only prints "connection failure" unless i replace userInput with "the@email.address" then it gives the correct result. I tried what you gave me. The query has the right email but it just prints "connection failure"

Comment: Print out the error to the console log and see what the problem is.  I don't think its a connection error.  I think its a malformed query.  As Patrick says above, you might need to delimit the quotes.